# Print value on console in spring JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, console

I am having spring application. Client side is jsp and to read value I use

```
<c:out value="${school.id}"></c:out>
```

But I want to print it on console. I don't know how to do that ?
I want to print this school object on console so I can read all the value inside this school object.

Please help me.

Comment: why not using simple sysout? like <% system.out.println("something"); %>

Comment: I am very new to this, I dont know if this is working or not ?

Comment: Which console are you referring to?

Comment: browser console